# Java, trying to create a specific network byte header based on length of command

Tags: java, python, sockets, byte, short

I'm running into some trouble when attempting to create a network byte header. The header should be 2 bytes long, which simply defines the length of the following command.

For example; The following command String `"HED>0123456789ABCDEF"` is 20 characters long, which is `0014` as hex signed 2 complement, creating the network byte header for this command works as the command is under 124 characters. The following snippet of code essentially works out the byte header and adds the following prefix to the command `\u00000\u0014` when the command is under 124 characters.

However for commands that are 124 characters or above, the code in the `if` block doesn't work. Therefore, I looked into possible alternatives and tried a couple of things regarding generating hex characters and setting them as the network byte header, but as they aren't bytes it's not going to work (As seen in the `else` block). Instead the `else` block simply returns `0090` for a command which is `153` characters long which is technically correct, but I'm not able to use this 'length' header the same way as the `if` blocks length header

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String commandHeader = "HED>";
    final String command = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    short commandLength = (short) (commandHeader.length() + command.length());
    char[] array;

    if( commandLength < 124 )
    {
        final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(commandLength);
        array = new String( bb.array() ).toCharArray();
    }
    else
    {
        final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(commandLength);
        array = convertToHex(bb.array());
    }

    final String command = new String(array) + commandHeader + command;
    System.out.println( command );
}

private static char[] convertToHex(byte[] data) {
    final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : data) {
        int halfByte = (b >>> 4) & 0x0F;
        int twoHalves = 0;
        do {
            if ((0 <= halfByte) && (halfByte <= 9))
                buf.append((char) ( '0' + halfByte));
            halfByte = b & 0x0F;
        } while (twoHalves++ < 1);
    }
    return buf.toString().toCharArray();
}
```

Furthermore, I have managed to get this working in Python 2 by doing the following three lines, no less! This returns the following network byte header for a 153 character command as `\x00\x99`

```
msg_length = len(str_header + str_command)
command_length = pack('>h', msg_length)
command = command_length + str_header + str_command
```

Also simply replicated by running Python 2 and entering the following commands:

```
In [1]: import struct
In [2]: struct.pack('>h', 153)
Out[2]: '\x00\x99'
```

Any assistance, or light that could be shed to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your message is inherently a *byte* sequence.  Why are you converting it to a character sequence? (A `String` in your particular case, but a `char[]`, `StringBuilder`, or `Reader` wouldn't be any better.)

Comment: And are we supposed to evaluate the Java code as if it did not explicitly discriminate between `if( commandLength < 124 )` and the alternative?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry if I didn't make it clear, I've edited the snippets to better reflect the Java code, and updated the description slightly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that you (try to) convert fundamentally binary data to character data.  Furthermore, you do it using the platform's default charset, which varies from machine to machine.

I think you have mischaracterized the problem slightly, however.  I am confident that it arises when `command.length()` is at least 124, so that `commandLength`, which includes the length of `commandHeader`, too, is at least 128.  You would also find that there are some (much) larger command lengths that worked, too.

The key point here is that when any of the bytes in the binary representation of the length have their most-significant bit set, that is meaningful to some character encodings, especially UTF-8, which is a common (but not universal) default.  Unless you get very lucky, binary lengths that have any such bytes will not be correctly decoded into characters in UTF-8.  Moreover, they may get decoded into characters successfully but differently on machines with that use different charsets for the purpose.

You also have another, related inconsistency.  You are formatting data for transmission over the network, which is a byte-oriented medium.  The transmission will be a sequence of bytes.  But you are measuring and reporting the number of *characters* in the decoded internal representation, not the number of *bytes* in the encoded representation that will go over the wire.  The two counts are the same for your example command, but they would differ for some strings that you could express in Java.

Additionally, your code is inconsistent with your description of the format wanted.  You say that the "network byte header" should be four bytes long, but your code emits only two.

You can address all these issues by taking character encoding explicitly into account, and by avoiding the unneeded and inappropriate conversion of raw binary data to character data.  The `ByteBuffer` class you're already using can help with that.  For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String commandHeader = "HED>";

    // a 128-byte command
    String command = "0123456789ABCDEF"
            + "0123456789ABCDEF"
            + "0123456789ABCDEF"
            + "0123456789ABCDEF"
            + "0123456789ABCDEF"
            + "0123456789ABCDEF"
            + "0123456789ABCDEF"
            + "0123456789ABCDEF";

    // Convert characters to bytes, and do so with a specified charset
    // Note that ALL Java implementations are required to support UTF-8
    byte[] commandHeaderBytes = commandHeader.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] commandBytes = command.getBytes("UTF-8");

    // Measure the command length in bytes, since that's what the receiver
    // will need to know
    int commandLength = commandHeaderBytes.length + commandBytes.length;

    // Build the whole message in your ByteBuffer
    // Allow a 4-byte length field, per spec
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(commandLength + 4);

    bb.putInt(commandLength)
            .put(commandHeaderBytes)
            .put(commandBytes);

    // DO NOT convert to a String or other character type.  Output the
    // bytes directly.
    System.out.write(bb.array());

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Hi John, apologies. When I was writing the question I was being misled by my understanding of the format, I've now rectified my error. Though no changes on your side are required. I'm just now looking into and understanding your answer, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Hi John, I managed to get a better look over your code this morning and tried it out, it worked without any issues. Comparing this to what I was attempting I can now see where I was going wrong all this time! Thanks for your answer and assistance.